# AnnData: Adding unaligned observations annotations

Tags: python, pandas

I have an AnnData (`adata`) and a pandas Dataframe (`df`). I would like left-join `adata.obs` and `df` on their index. How do I go about doing this? I tried using `pd.merge` and `adata.obs.join(df)` with no success. Both result in all the columns containing `NaN`. This shouldn't be the case since they share nearly all the same index values.

Answer (score 0):

You are on the right track with merge - the following works as expected:

```py
adata.obs = adata.obs.merge(how='left',right=df, left_index=True, right_index=True)
```

Note: Mismatch of dtypes (e.g. `str` in `adata.obs.index` and `int` in `df.index`) is a common source of errors.